# Crop raster files when importing with readGDAL from DB

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, r, rgdal

I have quite a lot of raster files stored in a PostgreSQL DB. Each of them has around 200MB and is representing EU-wide data. However I only need the the rasters to cover the area of Germany. I'm working in R.

I'd use readGDAL() in a loop to import the rasters:

```
-- # get list of files/tables with the help of the RPostgreSQL-package
x <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'efsa_spatial' AND table_name LIKE 'efsa_capri_%'")
crop <- x[, 3] -- # list of table names to iterate
raster_list <- vector(mode="list", length=length(crop))
for (i in seq(crop)) {
  -- # using readGDAL to import the rasters
  ras <- readGDAL(sprintf("PG:dbname='' host='' port='' user='' schema='efsa_spatial' table='%s' mode=2", crop[i]))
  raster_list[[substring(crop[i], 12)]] <- raster(ras, 1) 
}
```

Is it possible to crop the rasters simultaneously when performing readGDAL()? The best solution would be to use a shapefile / SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of Germany as a gauge, defining which raster cells are loaded. Is this possible? If not by using readGDAL(), are there other ways to do this?

I'm aware that I could do this easily after having loaded the files but as they are so big my intention is to reduce their size already in the course of importing.

I came up with such an idea because for all the vector data in this DB I used the RPostgreSQL-package to load the data into R. This allowed me to apply limitations to the data when importing (e.g "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_1 <= 100;") - But apparently the RPostgreSQL-package doesn't work with raster data.

Comment: readGDAL has arguments to read a window by offset and count

Comment: which ones do you mean? the argument offset defines the number of rows and columns to begin - so I can't use a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to outline my favored area. Also, regions.dim and output.dim don't seem to accept such input: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgdal/docs/asSGDF_GROD

Comment: You are supposed to figure it out, I know it's annoying but it's possible from the dims and scale.

Comment: But this window will be rectangular and not fitting to the area of polygon?

Comment: Not sure that you will be able to achieve this using readGDAL(), but you might consider doing this preprocessing step outside of R with  [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) and specifically the -cutline option

Comment: Er, you are mixing the idea of windowing with masking, any raster will crop to a rectangular window, masking applies rules to visibility and or missingness with that (I.e applied to a polygon within that bounding box). I consider windowing and masking as separate concepts, but you are right there's no inherent reason that you need the window crop independent of the masking. It's common in implementations though.)

Comment: I'm not thinking of masking. Rather on intersecting with a Polygon. Does this lead automatically to a rectangular raster? However I tried to use the offset argument to start at a different point `offset = c(4000000, 2500000)` and I get the following message: _Error: Failure during raster IO_ **BTW:** It's an .asc file (header: ncols 5900 nrows 4600 xllcorner 1500000 yllcorner 900000 cellsize 1000)